# android-How to enable Addressbar in Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

webview doesn't have an addressbar , is there anyway I could add an addressbar to it ?I've searched but I didn't find anything

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just cant :p It does not include any features of a fully developed web browser, such as navigation controls or an address bar. it just allows you to show webpages.

you can load url throug code:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

you can make an `EditText` with a `Button` and make your own addresbar..

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own compound view that consists of `EditText` and `WebView`. Then you can use your view as a mediator to the other views.